# Initializing UIViewController from storyboard returns base UIViewController rather than inherited version

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I'm attempting to initialize a viewcontroller from a storyboard but it always comes back with the type UIViewController rather than the inherited type of InheritedViewController. I can't figure out what could be causing this.  It does have all the other attributes that were specified in the storyboard but the type is incorrect.  So, all the overidden methods within the inherited class are not called.

[image: obj]

After tapping arrow in class field.

[image]

Comment: See the arrow next to InheritedViewController in the Class box at the top left? What happens if you click it?

Comment: It takes me to the InheritedViewController class but does also say symbol not found.  Updating my question with a screenshot.

Comment: The blue line in that screen shot tells me that you've changed the name of this view controller in order to take this screen shot. Not sure what to believe at this point.

Comment: I did change it to take the original screenshot and run a simpler case.

Comment: Did you try the usual trick where you quit Xcode, delete the DerivedData folder, and restart the computer?

Comment: Generally this means that the class of that name does not exist in the runtime.  If there was a typo in the class name somewhere, or if it's in a framework/library that is not linked in, or if that class was mistakenly unchecked from the files to compile into the binary, or there is a glitch in the DerivedData where it was not linked in, or something like that.  If you do "po NSClassFromString(@"InheritedViewController")" when paused in the debugger, I would expect that to return Nil.

Comment: @CarlLindberg My expectation would be different; in my experience, a class mentioned in the storyboard but not findable at runtime would not result in substitution of the superclass, but rather in a crash.

Comment: In older Xcode's this happened more often ... then you clear that class line and save and quit and restart and type it in again. It happened if you did some heavy editing on a storyboard. But I think you must also show how you instantiate that class and how you test its type that always comes back as UIVC as you say.

Comment: @AndrewBoissonnault - your code is instantiating the VC from *"TestStoryboard"* ... have you double-checked that you're not inadvertently setting the class in the wrong Storyboard?

Comment: make sure the methods to access from outside are exposed in the header file. 
This includes also `-(instancetype)init;` or similar.. initWithFrame.